# Finding similar strings in java

Tags: java, algorithm, string-comparison, words

I was wondering is there a kind of algorithm or pattern which allows you to compare and find similar words

It will be easier if I use example, here it is:

Supposing that we have a strig:

String keywords = "Mummy's girl";

ArrayList = "Mom, cat, dog, girlfriend, house, mum, girls, fire";

I want to get in result those words (cause they're similar or the same in writing) = "Mom, girlfriend, mum, girls, girl"

Comment: See https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein-Distanz for instance

Comment: Have fun with the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) but off course, you are off-topic, no external source should be ask in SO

Comment: You can use Levenshtein distance for basic text similarity metric, but "Mummy's" similarity to "Mom" is rather semantical (not too similar if taken as strings without meaning) - you'd need a synonym dictionary or thesuarus for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is little bit unclear. But in java you can use substring function.

```
         String n = in.next(); 
         String a = n.substring(0,3);
```

Here, a = Mum . Then go through all elements in the arraylist and find the similar word. In substring 0 is starting point and 3 is ending point.